# Getting a fatal error when trying to set up PFUser's profile picture

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, fatal-error, profile-picture

I was trying to set up the sign up page so that the user can set up a profile picture but as soon as i press the sign up button and it segues to the signup page it keeps crashing because of the profile picture codes. This is the button to set the profile picture

```
    @IBAction func setProfilePicture(sender: AnyObject) {
    let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    myPickerController.delegate = self
    myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    self.presentViewController(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    profilePictureIV.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

and this is the code to send the data to parse in the `viewDidLoad()` method

```
    let newUser = PFUser()
          let profilePicture = UIImageJPEGRepresentation((profilePictureIV?.image)!, 1)
          if(profilePicture != nil) {
              let profilePictureImageFile = PFFile(data: profilePicture!)
              newUser["profilePicture"] = profilePictureImageFile
          }
          ...
    }
```

The line that keeps crashing is the let profilePicture.... line giving an error:
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs when `profilePictureIV?.image` is nil while being unwrapped, so check it

```
let newUser = PFUser()
if let profilePicture = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profilePictureIV?.image, 1) {
   let profilePictureImageFile = PFFile(data: profilePicture)
   newUser["profilePicture"] = profilePictureImageFile
}
```

or

```
let newUser = PFUser()
if let profilePictureImage = profilePictureIV?.image {
   let profilePicture = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profilePictureImage, 1)!
   let profilePictureImageFile = PFFile(data: profilePicture)
   newUser["profilePicture"] = profilePictureImageFile
}
```

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. It gives me an error to fix it and replace `profilePictureIV?.image` with `(profilePictureIV?.image)!`

Comment: OH YAY! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!